# Manifolds embed in $\mathbb{R}^m$: How to check continuity?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

In James W. Vick's "Homology Theory: An Introduction to Algebraic Topology," Theorem 1 of Appendix II states that if $M$ is a compact $n$-manifold without boundary, then there is some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $M$ embeds homemorphically into $\mathbb{R}^m$. His proof proceeds as follows.

Let $N \in S^n$ denote the North Pole. Cover $M$ with finitely many open sets $U_1, ..., U_l$, each equipped with a homeomorphism $h_i:U_i \rightarrow S^n - \{N\}$. Define $\overline{h}_i: M \rightarrow S^n$ by $\overline{h}_i(x)=h_i(x)$ for $x\in U_i$, and $\overline{h}_i(x)=N$ for $x\in M-U_i$. Vick claims the maps $\overline{h}_i$ are continuous, so we get a homeomorphic embedding $M \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^{n+1})^l$ defined by $x \mapsto (\overline{h}_1(x), ..., \overline{h}_l(x))$.

Here is my question: how do we know $\overline{h}$ is continuous? I know this fact must rely on Hausdorffness because of the following counterexample. Take $M$ to be the circle with two South Poles, and obtain $U$ from $M$ by removing the North Pole and *one* of the South Poles. There is an obvious choice of homeomorphism $h:U \rightarrow S^1 - \{N\}$, and clearly the extension $\overline{h}$ is *not* continuous.

So how does the continuity of $\overline{h}$ follow from the Hausdorffness of $M$?

Comment: the $h$ in your example is not a homeomorphism because $U$ is not even connected.

Comment: I'm pretty sure $U$ is connected. Maybe I should have given a better description of the topology at play, but neither of the South Poles is an isolated point. So how would you write $U$ as the disjoint union of non-empty open sets?

Comment: I just got what you mean by two south poles. The problem is that the example you have is not a manifold. If $M$ is a manifold, then it should locally look like $\mathbb{R}^n$. The $h_i$'s in the proof are simply the coordinate charts of the manifold. Does this make sense?

Comment: The circle with two South Poles is a notorious example of a locally Eulcidean non-Hausdorff space. So yes, it does look like $\mathbb{R}^1$ locally.

Comment: CeyhunElmacioglu: Jephph's U is most definitely connected, and it is most definitely locally euclidean. It is even Hausdorff, so by any definition of "manifold" it is most definitely a manifold.

Comment: One slightly confusing issue here is that a homeomorphism written as 
"h : X → Y" is sometimes intended to mean only a homeomorphism of X *into* Y. But in this case Vick means each h_j is a homeomorphism of the domain *onto* the entire codomain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\overline h_i$ is continuous at all points $x\in U_i$ because its restriction to the neighbourhood $U_i$ of $x$, which is $h_i$, is continuous at $x$.

So let $x\notin U_i$. We need to prove that $\overline h_i$ is continuous at $x$, so let $V\subseteq S^n$ be an open neighbourhood of $\overline h_i(x)=N$. We know that $S^n\setminus V$ is a compact subset of $S^n\setminus\{N\}$ and therefore that $\overline h_i^{-1}(S^n\setminus V)=h_i^{-1}(S^n\setminus V)$ is a compact subset of $U_i$ (because $h_i$ is a homeomorphism), and therefore of $M$.
By the set-theoretic identity $f^{-1}(A)=(f^{-1}(A^\complement))^\complement$, we have $\overline h_i^{-1}(V)=M\setminus\overline h_i^{-1}(S^n\setminus V)$. So $\overline h_i^{-1}(V)$ is the complement of a compact subset, and therefore it's open.

Comment: This doesn't feel quite right. As mentioned in my post, the proof should vitally rely on Hausdorffness in some way, or else we can find counterexamples. How are you using Hausdorffness?

Comment: @Jephph Last line: compacts are closed.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks! That clears things up.